# copy/mutablecopy in array

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone SKD.I want to know that if i am copying(i mean mutable copy/copy) all objects from one array to another.
Here is my code:

```
NSSortDescriptor* DateSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lounge_rating" ascending:NO];
NSMutableArray *temp = [appdelegate.LongeListArray mutableCopy];
[temp sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:DateSorter]];
appdelegate.LongeListArray = temp;
[table reloadData];
[DateSorter release];
```

i want to know that should i release temp array or not?please help me.thanking you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Nuzhat is right but it will be better if you autorelease it rather then release other wise it may be generate memory leak.

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:appdelegate.LongeListArray]autorelease];
```

Comment: Hi @Dipen Chudasama, I didnt get you why it will generate memory leak if we release it?

Answer (score 2):

You should release any object that you copied or created ("alloc"), so yes you should release it.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `NSMutableArray *temp = [appdelegate.LongeListArray mutableCopy];`, that means you are creating copy of your existing object so its retain count will be 1.so its your responsibility to release this object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release any object that you allocated .